# PyQt Can't delegate combobox in 2 columns of qtableview, only works with 1

Tags: pyqt5, delegates

I can delegate ComboBox in TableView, but only 1 on 1 column. If i try to add the second one on a different column of the same table it fails.

Originally i've wanted to fill in data of combobox in 2nd cell based on information of the 1st cell. However adding 2nd combobox would be more than enough help.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super(TableModel, self).__init__()
        self._data = data

    def rowCount(self, index=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._data)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self._data[0])

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
                value = self._data[index.row()][index.column()]
                return str(value)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Orientation.Vertical:
            index = self.index(section, 0)
            return self.data(index, role)
        if role != Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole or orientation != Qt.Orientation.Horizontal:
            return QVariant()
        return self._data[0][section]

    def flags(self, index):
        if not index.isValid():
            return Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        return super().flags(index) | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._data[index.row()][index.column()] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index, [Qt.DisplayRole])
            return True
        return False

    def insertRows(self, new_row, position, rows, parent=QModelIndex()):
        position = (position + self.rowCount()) if position < 0 else position
        start, end = position, position + rows - 1

        if new_row == "":
            new_row = ['']*len(self._data[0])

        self.beginInsertRows(parent, start, end)
        self._data.append(new_row)
        self.endInsertRows()
        return True

    def removeRows(self, position, rows, QModelIndex):
        self.beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex, position, position+rows-1)
        for i in range(rows):
            del(self._data[position])
        self.endRemoveRows()
        return True

class ComboBoxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, items):
        super().__init__()
        self.items = items

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QComboBox(parent)
        editor.addItems(self.items)
        editor.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.commitAndCloseEditor)
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        value = index.model().data(index, role=Qt.DisplayRole)
        editor.setCurrentIndex(editor.findText(value))
        # Set tooltip for each item in the combobox
        for i in range(editor.count()):
            item_text = editor.itemText(i)
            item_tooltip = f" {item_text} "
            editor.setItemData(i, item_tooltip, role=Qt.ToolTipRole)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.currentText(), role=Qt.EditRole)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)

    def editorEvent(self, event, model, option, index):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            self.commitAndCloseEditor()
        return super().editorEvent(event, model, option, index)

    def commitAndCloseEditor(self):
        editor = self.sender()
        self.commitData.emit(editor)
        self.closeEditor.emit(editor, QAbstractItemDelegate.NoHint)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableView()

        data = [
          [4, 9, 2],
          [1, 0, 0],
          [3, 5, 0],
          [3, 3, 2],
          [7, 8, 9],
        ]

        self.model = TableModel(data)
        self.table.setModel(self.model)
        self.table.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QTableView.DoubleClicked)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.table)

        software_list = ['yolo', 'yupi']
        delegate = ComboBoxDelegate(sorted(software_list))
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegate)

        software_list2 = ['roko', 'boto']
        delegate2 = ComboBoxDelegate(sorted(software_list2))
        self.table.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, delegate2)

app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window=MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Keep a referencer to the delegates: e.g. `self.delegate = ComboBoxDelegate(software_list)`, etc.

Comment: Alternatively (and that would be suggested anyway), create the delegate with the view as a parent: change to `def __init__(self, items, parent=None):`, `super().__init__(parent)` and `ComboBoxDelegate(sorted(software_list), self.table)`.